# Stay connected BLE device even app is killed without notification for Android Oreo like Gear app

Tags: android, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

I connect to a BLE(Bluetooth low energy) device and want to stay connected even app is killed.

For Android Oreo version, I have tried to start foreground service for that purpose. However, the persistent notification in the lockscreen and notification bar is very annoying.

I know this feature comes with Android Oreo version, but I wonder how "Galaxy Wearable" app handles with this problem.

I have a Gear S3 smartwatch and this app connects to my watch and stay connected even app is killed without showing any notification to me.

I exactly want to connect like this way.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: as for how it should be according to the documentation, you have to use foreground service, and there is no other way. as for `Galaxy Wearable` - they *probably* found a hack, or another way, but none except them knows that, so please don't ask **us** how **they** did it.

Comment: Agree with above comment, best would be foreground Service. Probably Samsung made some customizations to their Android so that it's not permanently visible.